# What does the word Relational in "Relational Database" imply?

Tags: relational-database

I tried searching but didn't get any useful information.

What does the word "Relational" mean here? Is it tables being related to each other just like the real life entities, or does it mean something else?

Comment: That's, btw, the most common misconception about RDBMSes I hear.

Comment: @vartec: Is it the part I said about "relating to real life entities"?

Comment: The part "tables being related to each".

Comment: I think it's that every table defines a series of relationships within itself.

Comment: If you read French, read the first volumes of Bourbaki's [*Elements de mathématique*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89l%C3%A9ments_de_math%C3%A9matique). They explain what a "relation" is. Or read some book about [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database):

> A relational database matches data by
>   using common characteristics found
>   within the data set. The resulting
>   groups of data are organized and are
>   much easier for many people to
>   understand.

and further down:

> A relation is defined as a set of
>   tuples that have the same attributes.
>   A tuple usually represents an object
>   and information about that object.
>   Objects are typically physical objects
>   or concepts. A relation is usually
>   described as a table, which is
>   organized into rows and columns. All
>   the data referenced by an attribute
>   are in the same domain and conform to
>   the same constraints.

The tables are related to each other by common attributes that can then be used to form more complex queries for pulling data.

Comment: The last sentence of this answer goes back to the misunderstanding that "relational" refers to some relationship _between_ tables, but a "relation" is _a single table_.

Comment: @IMSoP, I agree, a *relation* is synonymous with "table". What is related (in this usage) are the individual columns of the table, which is why joining two tables then yields a new "relation". This jargon is however awkward, inconsistent with normal conceptualisations of tables, and it commandeers the English word "relation" (and by implication associated forms like "related") which are often desired to be used for more important purposes, so the word "relation" should never be used in practice to refer to a table.

Answer (score 14):

The word *relational* comes from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra which was invented by E.F. Codd.  SQL and relational databases started as an attempt to make Codd's ideas practical.

Comment: IIRC Codd based his ideas on the relational theory branch of mathematics. My DB theory classes were too long ago to remember where/when relational theory came from. Maybe some visitors from cstheory.stackexchange can correct me.

Answer (score 7):

A *relation* is a table in database context.

> A relation is a data structure which consists of a heading and an unordered set of tuples which share the same type. --[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28database%29)

It's more about how the data is related to the column name and type than how keys are related to foreign-keys.

> For example, a data set containing all the real-estate transactions in a town can be grouped by the year each transaction occurred, the sale price, a buyer's last name and so on. Such a grouping uses the relational model (a technical term for this is schema). Hence, such a database is called a "relational database." --[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database)

Comment: I think it's about more than just the names and types; a relation isn't just the _schema_ of a table, it's _a particular set of values_ which are considered "true" in a logical sense.

Answer (score 6):

This is very commonly misunderstood, and I think it's worth spelling out explicitly: **The "relation" in "relational" is not a synonym for "relationship".**

A "relation" is a concept taken from mathematical set theory, and refers to a subset of possible "tuples" (basically, records) which satisfy some proposition (condition).

So you might have a tuple type of `{ID, name}` where "ID" is constrained to be an integer, and "name" is constrained to be a string. `{12345, 'imsop'}`, `{96713, 'joebloggs'}`, and `{96713, 'imsop'}` are all *possible* values - they have the correct *type* - but only `{96713, 'imsop'}` represents an actual user of this site. So the relation "users" on this site would contain the tuple `{96713, 'imsop'}`, along with other tuples that are "true" for the proposition "represents a user of this site".

In SQL terms, a "tuple" is modelled as a "row", and a "relation" is modelled as a "table" or a "result set" (a distinction that doesn't exist in pure relational database theory). The original mathematical theory doesn't fully apply - for instance, relations are strictly unique, but SQL tables and result sets can contain duplicates - but the name "relational" has stuck because the basic principles remain.

**If there is any "relationship" implied, it is between the different tuples (rows) within a relation (table).** In the above example, all the tuples in the "users" relation are related by representing users of the site.

Bottom line is that mathematicians needed a name for a new type of thing, and re-used an English word. If they'd called them "setticles", we'd have "Setticular Database Management Systems".

Comment: +1 for "setticular"! We'd have been saved interminable confusion if it had been so-named!

Comment: @Steve I know, right? I might start using that from now on :P

Comment: Best answer.
The association of relation with relationship actually makes the name of relational vs non-relational databases a bit counterintuitive: someone without the knowledge of the mathematical definition of "relation" may actually be prone to switch the names around, and call relational to something like graph databases.

Comment: @Kelthar Indeed, it really only made sense in the context of the research Codd et al were doing, looking at data modelling as a mathematical problem, in contrast to previous approaches which often mimicked physical systems (e.g. hierarchies of catalogs and records). It's really rather unfortunate that the name stuck when SQL (which doesn't fully take that mathematical approach anyway) became the dominant technology.