# Do NoSQL and non-relational refer to the exact same concept?

Tags: database, relational-database, nosql, definition

**Question as the title says.** Of course, I already tried searching online, but did not find a definite answer yet. (The sources I checked imply that the terms are interchangeable, but do not state this explicitly.)

Also, if they are not the same, then **what is exactly the difference**?

Some thoughts from me:

- In theory, we could have a relational database, which is manipulated by some other language than SQL (and probably a couple instances do exist, at least at pet project level), but is there an example which is well-known and widely used in production as of today?
- I can't really imagine how the other way round (non-relational DB manipulated by SQL) would work, but maybe it is also possible? (The closest I can think of is querying a key-value DB with `SELECT` and returning `NULL`'s for the fields that are missing. But what would happen e.g. to `JOIN`'s? So maybe a non-relational DB would be possible which works with a **subset** of SQL; would that still count as an SQL DB though?)

Answer (score 7):

"NoSQL" doesn't consistently refer to any one concept, because it's a marketing term, not a technical one. See for instance [my answer on the DBA site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/287434/99395).

I think you have to look at the historical development of the term, rather than its face meaning: early databases were many and varied. Relational databases *in their theoretical purity* never actually took off, but *in the form expressed by SQL* they became the only game in town. So "an SQL database" for years meant "not one of those weird old-fashioned ones" - the reference was not just to the language, but to the entire philosophy it represented. Compare the term "PC", which now means neither "any computer that is personal" nor "something that is compatible with the 1981 IBM PC".

The term "relational database" was and is sometimes used as another term for this class of systems, but there are other technologies which are *more* relational, in the sense that they adhere to the mathematics of relational algebra or relational calculus more strictly than SQL. (For instance the SQL definition of a "table" doesn't quite match [the mathematical definition of a "relation"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/422044/96713).)

Later, when variety and experimentation became fashionable again, the "SQL" label was the obvious one to contrast with, hence "NoSQL". Again, it didn't actually mean "no use of the language SQL", it meant "something other than the class of database that's become ubiquitous".

There are absolutely ways of building a database which are not relational, but can be queried using SQL, or something very like it. A lot of analytical databases and "Big Data" tools do exactly this - they convert the familiar query terms into operations on some completely different data store - e.g. column-based database, or an indexed "data lake".

As I said on the linked answer, the only value of the term "NoSQL" is as a reminder that "SQL-relational" is no longer the only option you have. As a category, it's about as specific as "non-human".

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, yes, they largely do. The common point of most systems that call themselves "NoSQL" is not so much that they don't have a structured query language (many *do* have query languages, and some of them aren't actually all that different from SQL), but that they don't enforce a rigid schema on the data they contain.

Why exactly the term 'NoSQL' took off instead of something to do with schemas is hard to tell. Possibly the very success of the relational data model made the idea of abandoning SQL, which seemed inextricably linked to them, look so revolutionary as if that were the primary change.

Comment: From the standpoint of application developers that do not like dealing with SQL, the fact that SQL was no longer the part of the equation *was* the major change. Especially if the developers relied on DBAs for anything database-related. SQL was their only exposure to databases.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I think it was more a case of "you don't need SQL" than "you don't have to deal with SQL" - early "NoSQL" databases often had rather weak querying capabilities, but _justified_ that by claiming other advantages. If it was the case that developers don't like SQL as a language, it would have been much easier to build a new query language on top of an existing back-end; instead, the opposite has happened - SQL front-ends have been built for radically different back-ends, because SQL is familiar to people.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's how I understand and use the terms.  Non-relational is actually a slightly better term for this mainly because SQL is a language, not a data storage architecture.  I feel both terms are flawed, though, in that they describe what something is not instead of what it is.

There are alternate query languages for relation DBs.  For example Google has one called [Logica](https://logica.dev/) that works with its BigQuery database.

Additionally there are non-relational DBs that support SQL such e.g. [GraphDB](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/sql-access-over-jdbc.html).

Comment: _> There are alternate query languages for relation DBs._

Wouldn't this change the answer to the question to "no, they are not the same"? Logica would then be an example of NoSQL database which is relational (i.e. not non-relational). (And same for GraphDB which is non-relational, but "not NoSQL")

Comment: @Attilio Logica is a language, not a DB, and it actually compiles to SQL.  The database is called BigQuery and I believe it is relational but I don't know much about it really.  But the term 'NoSQL' is used for graph DBs even if they do support SQL.  NoSQL is an imprecise/inaccurate term which is why I think 'non-relational' is better.

Comment: In some ways, SQL *is* an architecture, because it defines a lot of concepts we expect to exist in all such systems (tables, columns, result sets); those aren't quite the same as the concepts originally proposed for "relational" databases, so purists would argue that an "SQL DBMS" is not actually a "relational DBMS". I guess most "NoSQL" systems are "not even remotely relational", though, so perhaps "non-relational" does work.

Comment: @IMSoP I guess what I mean by that (other than the obvious 'L' stands for language) is that you could create a relational database and not support SQL at all. The example of BigQuery/Logica kind of falls flat because they are simply transpiling to SQL from Logica but I think it's easy to see that you could have a relational DB where you use something like Logica (i.e. a Prolog/Datalog derivative) as the primary or sole query language.  The term NoSQL took off because of a backlash against SQL, which I get, but I still think it's flawed and I'm sure I'm not the only one.

Comment: @IMSoP Not trying to spam you here but I really think [this article](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2021/04/logica-organizing-your-data-queries.html) hits the nail on the head:  "The main flaw of SQL, however, lies in its very limited support for abstraction."  This is what, I think, is the root of the backlash against SQL and the genesis of the 'NoSQL' moniker.

Comment: "in that they describe what something is not instead of what it is." - you might be interested, there is a philosophy in linguistics that argues **all language** works like that, words don't describe what something is so much as excludes everything that it isn't. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_in_General_Linguistics

Comment: @JimmyJames, certainly "abstraction" - in other words, modular, re-usable pieces of logic - is a deficiency in SQL. But I think the predominant opposition to SQL came from those who simply didn't understand the importance of its basic features and facilities, as can always be seen from the proposed alternatives.

Comment: @JimmyJames That's an interesting article, but I don't think it's what "NoSQL" was about when the term was coined 10+ years ago. Back then, the backlash was against *a database monoculture*; SQL was the name of that monoculture, because it was the standard everything followed (or claimed to). The new databases challenged *everything*: schemas, normalisation, strong consistency, etc. Neither "SQL" nor "relational" cover all that if taken strictly, both are just labels for the still-dominant style of database, and "NoSQL" means anything outside that style.

Comment: @IMSoP I agree with what you are saying.  I may need to be more clear: all of those things that you mention are true but really don't have that much to do with SQL.  What I mean is that the term 'NoSQL' became the term because people were frustrated with SQL and the idea of not having to use SQL was appealing to those who didn't know it (or knew too much.)  But as I think you point out, that is really orthogonal to a lot of what the various flavors of NoSQL are actually about.

Comment: @whatsisname That might make sense on a certain level but I don't think that's really what we are talking about.  It's not like I refer to you, IMSoP, myself, and the OP as 'not Socrates'.  It's true that we are all 'not Socrates' but it's not a very useful way to name people.  It's rare to find a situation where saying it's not something helps illuminate what it is.  With the term NoSQL we are left to wonder what it is and then find out that it actually means, 'maybe SQL'.

Comment: @JimmyJames You might be right, but I've never heard that argument before, and I think it's taking the term too literally and trying to reverse-engineer an etymology. People talk about "an SQL database" like they talk about "a PC"; they don't think about what the acronym stands for, it's just a label for that technology. That's where the "SQL" in "NoSQL" comes from. Early "NoSQL" systems had much *less* expressive query languages, because they were focusing on other concepts, like storing a multi-dimensional domain object in one record rather than normalised across multiple tables.

Comment: @IMSoP Yeah, I should clarify, that's my personal take on what happened.  It's based on my recollection of articles and presentations.  It's also probably related to my own experience of working with a lot of highly (perhaps overly) complicated SQL.  I think the idea that SQL lacks good abstraction is correct.  Trying to determine whether two complex queries are equivalent (especially when the underlying structures have changed) is a tough problem and I'm not aware of effective tooling that can help.